# Extending 20AWG of Ikea VAXMYRA, What to look out for

Tags: voltage, safety

I am looking to extend the current wire of Ikea VAXMYRA led light. From the wire there's printing of AWM 2468 20AWG 80oC 300V. Can I literally just purchase another 20 AWG cable and splice it? Please advise, I have no knowledge with electrical. I am worried about any potential electrical hazzard.

Comment: If the light and/or wires use 120 volts, probably not since you would be modifying it.  If the wires are carrying/using less than 50 volts, then possible.

Comment: The Ansluta intermediate connection cord appears to solve. your problem. https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/ansluta-intermediate-connection-cord-60119925/

Answer (score 3):

The lights are low voltage 24V with a separate ANSLUTA driver. You should not make any modifications to the ANSLUTA. But extending the VAXMYRA is a very safe thing to do because the voltage (24V) and current (a tiny fraction of an Amp - power per light is only 1.4W) are both low.

That being said, I would *not* go with 20 AWG. I would actually use somewhat larger wire for a number of reasons. AWG is "backwards" - e.g., 18 AWG is larger than 20 AWG.

How to do this? That depends on the type of connectors and wires. With a fairly standard connector, you buy or make an extension cord with a male connector on one end and a female connector on the other end. However, it is not clear from the IKEA web pages what kind of connectors these lights use. The alternative is to cut the existing wire and splice in a longer wire. Depending on the existing wire type (solid vs. stranded, type of insulation, etc.) that may be really easy to do or may be very hard. The actual connection could be done with tan or blue wire nuts (Ideal brand - other brands mostly use the same colors but check specifications to be sure) or other wire connectors - there are several different types, the main thing is to make sure they can handle 20 AWG wire.

Comment: Under cab lights like these are typically roughed in with 18/2 to the light location with all the 18/2 wires leading back to a connection point for the driver.  Hardest part is as you say stripping the wire insulation for the splice on the 20 awg wires.